# Is there any limit on number of SHA1 keys that can be added to Firebase project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, sha1

Firebase authentication requires adding SHA1 keys to all apps of the Firebase project.
But, there can be any number of flavors of the android app for which new app in firebase project has to be created.
When I was adding SHA1 to all apps inside our Firebase apps it used to stop accepting SHA1's after some number of them being added.
*(around 32 to 37, not a constant.)* It only stated there is some error and asked to try again later.

- Is there any limit on number of apps that can be created in a single
  Firebase project?
- Is there any number of limit to number of SHA1
  that can be added to single Firebase project or a Firebase account.

we are using **Free plan** of Firebase

Comment: what you need 37 keys per project for?

Comment: There is indeed a limit on the number of apps per project. It's not a fixed number, so it's hard to be certain if you're hitting that. [Reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: as of now, the app has 4 build flavours, (stage, prod, QA, dev) and it has 4 clients. So, total distinct packages are 16 as of now. It takes only 9 clients to reach the firebase limit. I understand that will be the point to contact to Firebase support and buy extra privileges from firebase.